# Python web based interpreter security issues

Tags: python, linux, bash, security

I am making a web based python interpreter which will take code executes it on Linux based python3 interpreter and give output on the same web page. But this has some serious loop holes like someone can execute bash script using python's `os` module, can check directory for source code of the web application and a lot more.

Can anyone suggest me how to prevent this kind of mishaps in my application
Regards

Comment: You will need to sanitized the user inputs.  This is a broad answer to a broad question.

Comment: It's called sandboxing. Googling "Python sandbox" should have a pile of good suggestions

Comment: @thatotherguy This is what I was looking for Regards

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: there is no easy "python-only" solution for this.

Some details:

- user can always try to call `os`, `sys`, `with open(SENSITIVE_PATH, 'rw') as f: ...`, etc, and it's hard to detect all those cases simply by analyzing the code
- If you allow ANY third-party, then things become even more complicated, for example some third-party package may locally create an alias to `os.execv` (`os_ex = os.execv`), and after this it will be possible to write a script like `from thirdparty.some_internals import os_ex; os_ex(...)`.

The more or less reliable solution is to use "external sandboxing" solutions:

- Run interpreter in the unprivileged docker container. For example:

  1. write untrusted script to some file that will be exposed through volume in the docker container
  2. execute that script in docker:

     a. `subprocess.call(['docker', 'exec', 'CONTAINER_ID', '/usr/bin/python', 'PATH_TO_SCRIPT'])`

     b. `subprocess.call(['docker', 'exec', 'CONTAINER_ID', '/usr/bin/python', '-c', UNTRUSTED_SCRIPT_TEXT])`
- Use PyPy-s [sandbox](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html).
- Search for some "secure" [IPython kernel for Jupyter notebook server](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels). Or [write your own](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wrapperkernels.html). Note: existing kernels are not guaranteed to be secure and may allow to call `subprocess.check_output`, `os.rm` and others. So for "default kernel" it's still better to run Jupyter server in the isolated environment.
- Run interpreter in [`chroot`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chroot) using unprivileged user. Different implementations have different level of "safety".
- Use Jython with [finely tuned permissions](http://alphaloop.blogspot.com/2014/08/sandboxing-python-scripts-in-java.html).
- Some exotic solutions like "client-side JS python implementation": [brython](https://brython.info/), [pyjs](http://pyjs.org/)

In any case, even if you manage to implement or reuse existing "sandbox" you still will get many potential problems:

- If multiprocessing or multithreading is allowed then you might want to monitor how CPU resources are utilized, because
  some scripts might want to use EVERYTHING. Even with GIL it's possible for multi-threading to utilize all kernels (all the user has to do is to call functions that use c-libraries in the threads)
- You might want to monitor memory usage, because some scripts might leak or simply use a lot of memory
- Other candidates for monitoring: Disk IO usage, Network usage, open file descriptors usage, execution time, etc...
- Also you should always check for security updates of your "sandboxing solution", because even docker sometimes is vulnerable and [makes it possible to execute code on host machine](https://seclists.org/oss-sec/2019/q1/119)

Recommended read: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191623/best-practices-for-execution-of-untrusted-code